# Apache POI writes only one record

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am writing some data into excel file using `Apache POI` but for some reason the file shows only the last record (1 record only). I have list of POLJO that I am passing. I am also iterating through the cells but all I get is just one record.

Method to write in excel

```
public void writeToExcel(List<NYProgramTO> to){
    try {
        Workbook workBook = new HSSFWorkbook();
        CreationHelper helper = workBook.getCreationHelper();
        Sheet sheet = workBook.createSheet("NY_PPA_P3_Sheet");

        Row headerRow = sheet.createRow(0);
        headerRow.createCell(0).setCellValue("First Name");
        headerRow.createCell(1).setCellValue("Last Name");
        headerRow.createCell(2).setCellValue("Policy Number");
        headerRow.createCell(3).setCellValue("Zip Code");
        headerRow.createCell(4).setCellValue("Date of Birth");

        if(to != null){
            int size = to.size();

            for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
                NYProgramTO nyP= to.get(i);
                Row row = sheet.createRow(1);
                row.createCell(0).setCellValue(nyP.getFirstName());
                row.createCell(1).setCellValue(nyP.getLastName());
                row.createCell(2).setCellValue(nyP.getPolicyNumber());
                row.createCell(3).setCellValue(nyP.getZipCode());
                row.createCell(4).setCellValue(nyP.getDateOfBirth());
            }
        }
        FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream("NY_PPA_P3.xlsx");
        workBook.write(stream);
        stream.close();
        System.out.println("NY_PPA_P3.xlsx created successfully.");

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by "only one record" you mean that only one row is appearing, this is probably easily fixable by making sure that you increment the **Row** that is being created before writing the Cells.

Try changing:

```
Row row = sheet.createRow(1);
```

to:

```
Row row = sheet.createRow(i+1);
```